# Mount BTRFS Partition

Tags: mount, linux-mint, btrfs

I am trying to mount a BTRFS partition in Linux Mint KDE.

This is my fdisk -l for the relevant device

```
Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            32    4096031    4096000     2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       4096032    4608031     512000   250M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3       4608032 1953092263 1948484232 929.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       4608040 1953092263 1948484224 929.1G 8e Linux LVM
```

I have tried `sudo mount -t btrfs /dev/sdb5 /mnt/serverdisk`
and I got `mount: /dev/sdb5 is already mounted or /mnt/serverdisk busy`

and I tried `sudo mount -t btrfs /dev/sdb3 /mnt/serverdisk`
and I got this

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

As far as I can tell /dev/sdb5 is not busy.

How can I mount this partition.

Note: In Dolphin it appears that the whole disk is incorrectly mounted as "C" when I click on it I get

```
An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting system-managed device /dev/dm-0: Command-line `mount "/mnt/c"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/c-c,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

The 2GB first Partition is also detected and displayed under devices but when I click on it I get the same error.

Mint is running in a VM. This is a drive that I have loaded in a SATA-USB dock and I am giving the guest access to the entire physical disk.

**Edit:**

I have now tried the solution here [How to mount an LVM volume?](https://superuser.com/questions/116617/how-to-mount-an-lvm-volume). I have followed the steps successfully until the mount.

With the LV being c and the VG being c

I have tried

```
 sudo mount /dev/c/c /mnt/serverdisk -o ro,user
```

and I have tried

```
sudo mount -t btrfs /dev/c/c /mnt/serverdisk -o ro,user
```

The result I get for both commands is

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

for the first command with no file system specified I got this in after doing dmesg

```
[ 1114.590972] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 1114.590975] EXT4-fs (dm-0): bad block size 16384
```

for the second command there was nothing in the log.

**Edit2:**

After doing some reading it appears the 16384 byte block size of the volume maybe be the problem. Is there any way I can shrink the block size on the drive with out losing data?

Comment: "Mint is running in a VM." Does the host OS have the drive mounted? That might give you the drive busy message...

Comment: The host is Windows 10, it can't mount anything on the drive as far as I know. It's not present in File Explorer. So I assume it is not mounted

Comment: `Linux LVM` as partition type? So maybe [*How to mount an LVM volume?*](https://superuser.com/q/116617/432690)

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: Thanks, I tried that but I am still unsuccessful. I updated my question with the results.

Comment: check Drive Manager and see if the drive is showing as "online". diskpart should be able to tell you too...