# How to mount an LVM volume from a dd/raw/vmdk image?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, lvm, forensics

Input: RAW/DD Image of an HDD. `fdisk -l` shows partitions

```
fdisk -l image.dd 
Disk image.dd: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00093f57

Device            Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
image-1.dd1 *      2048   499711   497664  243M 83 Linux
image-1.dd2      501758 31455231 30953474 14.8G  5 Extended
image-1.dd5      501760 31455231 30953472 14.8G 8e Linux LVM
```

Trying to mount it using `start-sector*sector size` (as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/821681/864617); common for mounting partitions) brings error

```
(„mount: /mnt/vmdisk: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.“
```

The most sufficent solutions can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/116617/how-to-mount-an-lvm-volume) using `lvm2` tools like `vgscan`, `vgchange`, `lvs`; but these tools **does not have an option to scan in a raw file** for these volumes.

So how would it be possible to access the content of the `Linux LVM` using `mount` or something similar?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks!! That was the final step which was missing - Included your step in the overall answer below :)

Comment: This is the second post I've seen doing this - there is no need to use `sudo` for running `fdisk` against a disk image file (assuming your user has read access to the file). Running `sudo` when you don't have to can be dangerous...

Answer (score 16):

Install kpartx

```
sudo apt-get install kpartx
```

Integrate the volumes in `dev/mapper` using

```
sudo kpartx -a -v image.dd
```

Check `dev/mapper` to see your partitions

```
administrator@cdc-ansible:~$ ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 19 12:50 123--yourname--ewu--vg-root -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 19 12:50 123--yourname--ewu--vg-swap_1 -> ../dm-4
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Nov 19 07:59 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 19 12:50 loop2p1 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 19 12:50 loop2p2 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Nov 19 12:50 loop2p5 -> ../dm-2
```

Afterwards `sudo lvscan`to find the name of the lv's:

```
sudo lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/123--yourname--ewu--vg/root' [12.71 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/123--yourname--ewu--vg/swap_1' [<2.00 GiB] inherit
```

Try to mount it again:

```
sudo mount /dev/123--yourname--ewu--vg/root /mnt/rootfs
```

The mounted file system (tada!):

```
ll /mnt/rootfs/
total 116
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Oct 30 09:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Nov 19 12:59 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 30 09:35 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 102 root root 12288 Oct 30 09:37 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Nov 11  2016 home/
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Nov 24  2017 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  2  2018 lib64/
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Sep 28  2015 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 24  2017 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Aug 26  2016 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 10  2014 proc/
drwx------   7 root root  4096 Oct  9 10:08 root/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Oct 30 09:35 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 22  2014 srv/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 13  2014 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   8 root root  4096 Oct 30 09:43 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Sep 28  2015 var/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Oct 30 09:36 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic
```

Thanks to these sources [1](http://www.utilities-online.info/articles/Mount-an-LVM-partition-image-cloned-with-dd/#.W_K3mCeNzRZ) [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/766141/864617) [3](https://superuser.com/a/116631/536168)

And by the way, if you are coming from another image type (such as VMDK,VDI,...) use [this link](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html) to convert it to DD.